Customize board into 16x8 in chess using package chess.js or react-chessboard
I made a chess game, then I wanted to change the rules in it such as making the board bigger with a size of 16x8 and also changing the turn base system to a cooldown system
I was trying to customize it even into the node_modules I still can't make it. I just can create the baord but for the pawn it still on the normal posisition.
How can I customize the funtion and also the board on my chess game using react, react-chessboard, and chess.js
